# Finding number of hits to an action class in struts

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Is it possible to find the number of times an action class was accessed in struts? Interview question?

Comment: what about a static field which will get increased (within synchronize) on each call?

Comment: Not a good interview question.

Comment: @StevenBenitez:i am fully agree with you but its very common to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Parse the container's access log.

This is the most-generic, most-flexible, most-common solution, and there are tons of tools to do this.

If that isn't an acceptable answer (and if it isn't, and it's an interview, be afraid) then I'd actually do it with a filter or interceptor, keeping a map keyed by URL with synchronized write access, updating a count for the URL (minus query string if present) on every request. If it needs to be persisted, it can be.

That and a combination of the S2 configuration will give you a pretty precise view into request stats.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is to store it in the database/Application Context or file, since Struts2 action also work as Data Object so framework create an unique instance of Action for each request so as to make them thread safe.
You can add your counter logic in prepare method which will get called before any of the Action method call.

Still there are many points which needs to be answered before it.

1. There any many cases when actual action will not get called and interceptor will send back the flow.
2. By Action call do we mean specific method call of action or only action instance creation.

we can not put the logic in interceptors as interceptors are not created for each request and its not safe to save action specific data in interceptors.